# How can I programmatically select the select menu?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, select, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a select

```
<v-row v-for="(rule, index) in rules" :key="rule.id">
    <v-select dense outlined :items="attributes" item-text="name" item-value="id" v-model="rules[index].attribute" label="Attribute"></v-select>
</v-row>
```

where `this.attributes` =

```
[ { "id": 1, "name": "Style name", "alias": null, "attribute": "STYLE_NAME", "category_id": 1, "data_type_id": 3, "data_type_name": "String" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Country", "alias": null, "attribute": "COUNTRY_NAME", "category_id": 2, "data_type_id": 3, "data_type_name": "String" }, { "id": 3, "name": "Serial number", "alias": null, "attribute": "scanstring", "category_id": 3, "data_type_id": 3, "data_type_name": "String" }, { "id": 4, "name": "Brand Name", "alias": null, "attribute": "BRAND_NAME", "category_id": 1, "data_type_id": 3, "data_type_name": "String" }, { "id": 5, "name": "Account/Customer Name", "alias": null, "attribute": "CUSTOMER_NAME", "category_id": 1, "data_type_id": 3, "data_type_name": "String" }, { "id": 6, "name": "Product UPC", "alias": null, "attribute": "PRODUCT_UPC", "category_id": 1, "data_type_id": 3, "data_type_name": "String" }, { "id": 7, "name": "Label batch", "alias": null, "attribute": "LABEL_HEADER_ID", "category_id": 3, "data_type_id": 1, "data_type_name": "Number" }, { "id": 8, "name": "Current time", "alias": null, "attribute": "time(convert_tz(now(),'UTC','${PARAM}'))", "category_id": 4, "data_type_id": 5, "data_type_name": "Time" } ]
```

I tried add a test :

TEST : `{{ rules[index].attribute }}` ==> `Serial number`

Then that lead my select to look like this

[image]

As you can see it has a

```
v-model="rules[index].attribute"
```

and `rules[index].attribute` = `Serial number`, why is my select is not selected Serial number on page load. It just show this

[image]

I was hoping to see sth like this :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In mounted hook initialize the bound property `rules[0].attribute` to the first item of `attributes` :

```js
mounted(){
  this.$set(this.rules,0,{...this.rules[0],attribute:this.attributes[0]})
}
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, I update my variable name since it's in the v-for, v-model updated to `rules[index].attribute`

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, it's not working, please see it : https://pasteboard.co/IRvyazVN9OvF.png

Comment: Have you look at my result above ? I hope you can suggest a working solution instead, thanks for your help so far;

Comment: Yes I looked, and I'm doing my best to find a the good solution

Comment: what about `this.rules[0].attribute=this.attributes[0]`?

Comment: the above suggestion may not work for reactivity issue, try also `this.$set(this.rules,0,{...this.rules[0],attribute:this.attributes[0]})`

Comment: Why does vue.js make it so complicated ???   in jQuery only 1 line, sth like this  `$('#.attribute').val('Serial number');`

Comment: It's not getting set stilll even with the latest code.